# Yearling, but not reputation points earned

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, yearling-badge

If I understood correctly when you became a yearling you earn 200 reputation points, right? was that changed or I missunderstood? I would like to have those points for opening some questions with bounty

Comment: [citation needed]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You misunderstood, unfortunately.

Yearling is awarded for *having* at least 200 points. You don't actually earn reputation for it, or any other badge for that matter.

Comment: haha.. well, it was funny how I missunderstood it

Comment: I'm not sure this is right, either. The badge can recur each year, and so I think you get it for earning 200 reputation over the course of the previous year.  Otherwise everyone with >200 rep would get the yearling every year.

Comment: @Joel It's having 200 reputation per year, yes, but I was glossing over that fact because what's important to this question is not how much per year, but that it's a requirement and not a reward. Exact formula, [from here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-is-each-badge/68258#68258), is `reputation ≥ (number of years as an active user) × 200`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the badge `yearling`, you must have earned 200 points of reputation during that year at least. There is no reputation reward involved with this.